# SlimFramework + PHP-View

Tags: php, view, slim

Fiz o *download* da biblioteca [Php-View](https://github.com/slimphp/PHP-View) para usar junto ao Slim Framework 3.x, porém não estou conseguindo fazer o retorno da *view*.

```
// Get container
$container = $app->getContainer();

// Register component on container
$container['view'] = function ($container) {
  return new \Slim\Views\PhpRenderer('App/resources/views');
};

$app->get('/', function($request, $response) {
  $tes = new \App\Teste(); // Usando Eloquent ORM
  $tes->nome = "OI";
  return $this->view->render($response, "home.php", array("obj" => $tes->nome));
});
$app->run();
```

Se eu fizer um `var_dump($tes)`, recebo o objeto normalmente, porém se eu tentar chamar a *view* só recebo o erro

> A website error has occurred. Sorry for the temporary inconvenience.

Answer (score 1):

Encontrei o erro;

O mesmo estava na declaracão do `path` para os arquivos

```
return new \Slim\Views\PhpRenderer('App/resources/views');
```

Faltava uma ultima barra `/` depois de `views`.

```
return new \Slim\Views\PhpRenderer('App/resources/views/');
```